# FileNotFoundError on aws Lambda when concatenating videos with ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, file-not-found

Goal :

- Concat 2 videos (both are in an s3 bucket) via aws Lambda using ffmpeg
- Upload the resultant output.mp4 to another S3 bucket
- Python 3+

I've already created a layer containing a static ffmpeg

The Error :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/output.mp4'",
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      19,
      "lambda_handler",
      "s3.Object(bucketLowRes, mp4OutputFileName).put(Body=open(new_file_key, 'rb'))"
    ]
  ]
}
```

My Lambda function :

```
import json
import os
import subprocess
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucketLowRes = s3.Bucket("bucket-conc-lowres")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement

    mp4OutputFileName = 'output.mp4'

    new_file_key = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.sep, 'tmp', mp4OutputFileName))
    subprocess.call( ['/opt/ffmpeg', '-i', 'concat:s3://bucket-word-clips/00th76kqwfs915hbixycb77y9v3riwsj30.mp4|s3://bucket-word-clips/00uoakp6jyafbu13ycvl6w2i9tj42eux30.mp4', new_file_key ] )

    s3.Object(bucketLowRes, mp4OutputFileName).put(Body=open(new_file_key, 'rb'))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

**Question :**

- FileNotFoundError : Where is the output mp4 file of my ffmpeg concat being saved ??
- And if it is being saved to /tmp/output.mp4 , then why the FileNotFoundError ??

thanks

Comment: Have you checked the output of ffmpeg for errors? Does it successfully concat the videos? That would seem like the most obvious cause for FileNotFound despite using the exact same path

Comment: The merged file would be in the temp filesystem of the Lambda function, it's most likely that the merge did not succeed, so the file is not being saved. When you try to save the new file to S3 you get the `FileNotFoundError`. Can you merge those files successfully locally?

Comment: Don't use the concat protocol with MP4. Use the concat demuxer or concat filter instead.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I get this issue when I run the command in aws lambda function:

Comment: Were you able to find the root cause of this issue? If you were, please share the solution, here. Thanks!